# Business rules and validation with Spring AOP, Specification pattern and Strategy pattern

Tags: spring, validation, design-patterns, specifications

I really have **trouble with validation and business rules programming(design)** within Spring application standard architecture (controller -> service -> DAO...).

Bit by bit, **service layer** classes **are becoming overloaded with ugly if-s**, naive-refactored methods which unifies some common validations on class level etc. Simply, all this requires a some more refactoring practice to make code more maintainable.

I know for Business Rule Management Systems, and things like Hibernate Validator, but **i don't want to use third party solutions if possible**.

Recently, I read about **Domain Driver Design and Specification pattern** looks like attractive solution for business rules organization. I have also read different views about Spring and DDD combination.

Because i'm beginner, probably my idea will look naive, but i **was thinking to combine AOP** capabilities of Spring framework **and Specification pattern** as convenience approach to formulate business rules and logic. In that combination, AOP would be used just to insert specific business rule in specific service method. As some extension, i thought that maybe **Strategy pattern** will help for defining different validation strategies.

But, many questions arises. How to variate strategy according to validation context, class number explosion, pattern overusage etc?

I just want to hear some **thoughts** about this idea **and advices** about mentioned problem. Thanks